# org-export to different directory

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I would like to export my `org` file to a different directory than the one containing the base org file. I've tried setting the property `EXPORT_FILE_NAME`:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_FILE_NAME: ./export/test
:END:
```

When I export the subtree that has this property drawer attached with `C-c C-e l p`, I'm seeing the following (surprising) behavior.

The `.tex` file is produced in ./export, as desired.
The `.pdf' file is produced in the original directory.

How can I get *both* the `.tex` and the `.pdf` to show up in the other directory?

Here's a MWE of my org file:

```
#+TITLE: latex org-mode testing

* Exporting to different directory
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_FILE_NAME: ./export/test
:END:

This is the material in the test file.
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the problem is with the way the latex compiler is called. Its own working directory is the original directory of the `.org` file, not the new directory of the `.tex` file. So that means that while it finds the `.tex` file in the correct directory (/export), its own working directory is still `./`, so that's where it puts the output files. I had to explicitly specify the output directory.  Adding the option `-output-directory=%o` to the command `org-latex-pdf-process` solved the problem.

Comment: Bernhard can you maybe share some configuration code for the emacs noobs like me?

Comment: @AlwynSchoeman I have in my emacs `init.el` (or `.emacs`): ```(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))```  Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to work when using the `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` property - the `.tex` file is exported correctly, but pdflatex fails to compile...